# Whats the best way to mirror a live Cassandra cluster for analytics tasks?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Assuming a live cluster with several DCs, whats the best way to setup some nodes that are dedicated for analytic queries?

Analytic nodes will be hosted in a separate (routed) network and must not write any data back to the production nodes. They also must not be counted against for any CL. This especially applies to EACH_QUORUM that will be used for some writes. Analytics nodes may be offline at any time.

All solutions I've looked into seem to have their own drawbacks.

1) Take snapshots on production and transfer to independent analytics cluster

- Significant update delay
- IO intensive either on network or disk (e.g. rsync)
- Lots of duplicate data due to different replication factors (3:1 prod. vs analytics)
- Mismatch in SSTable row ranges and cluster topology on analytics cluster may require to use sstableloader

2) Use [write survey mode](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-1-live-traffic-sampling) to establish read-only nodes

- Not 100% sure how this could be done for setting up multiple survey nodes to cover the whole ring
- Queries can only be executed against each node locally as they could not be part of a coordinated execution

3) Add regular DC dedicated for analytics

- EACH_QUORUM will fail in case analytics cluster is not available
- Queries on production should not be served from analytics
- Would require a way to prevent users on analytics to be able to execute queries or updates on production

Any other options or existing tools that could be used?

Comment: I'm going to explore using triggers to mirror writes. There is this article too:

https://dzone.com/articles/cassandra-to-kafka-data-pipeline-part-1